# PDF Convert to Black And White PNGs

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, system.drawing

I'm trying to compress PDFs using iTextSharp. There are a lot of pages with color images stored as JPEGs (DCTDECODE)...so I'm converting them to black and white PNGs and replacing them in the document (the PNG is much smaller than a JPG for black and white format)

I have the following methods:

```
    private static bool TryCompressPdfImages(PdfReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            int n = reader.XrefSize;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                PdfObject obj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);
                if (obj == null || !obj.IsStream())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var dict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
                var subType = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
                if (!PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subType))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var stream = (PRStream)obj;
                try
                {
                    var image = new PdfImageObject(stream);

                    Image img = image.GetDrawingImage();
                    if (img == null) continue;

                    using (img)
                    {
                        int width = img.Width;
                        int height = img.Height;

                        using (var msImg = new MemoryStream())
                        using (var bw = img.ToBlackAndWhite())
                        {
                            bw.Save(msImg, ImageFormat.Png);
                            msImg.Position = 0;
                            stream.SetData(msImg.ToArray(), false, PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION);
                            stream.Put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
                            stream.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
                            stream.Put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.FLATEDECODE);
                            stream.Put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(width));
                            stream.Put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(height));
                            stream.Put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
                            stream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
                            stream.Put(PdfName.LENGTH, new PdfNumber(msImg.Length));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    // may or may not help      
                    reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Image ToBlackAndWhite(this Image image)
    {
        image = new Bitmap(image);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            var grayMatrix = new[]
            {
                new[] {0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0, 0},
                new[] {0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0, 0},
                new[] {0.114f, 0.114f, 0.114f, 0, 0},
                new [] {0f, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                new [] {0f, 0, 0, 0, 1}
            };

            var ia = new ImageAttributes();
            ia.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(grayMatrix));
            ia.SetThreshold((float)0.8); // Change this threshold as needed
            var rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            gr.DrawImage(image, rc, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

I've tried varieties of COLORSPACEs and BITSPERCOMPONENTs, but always get "Insufficient data for an image", "Out of memory", or "An error exists on this page" upon trying to open the resulting PDF...so I must be doing it wrong. I'm pretty sure FLATEDECODE is the right thing to use.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you using FLATEDECODE? That's ZIP compression, aren't you looking for DCTDECODE (which would refer to JPEG compression)?

Comment: In the question - as I mention, I'm trying to embed a PNG format

Comment: PNGs cannot be embedded as is in PDFs. Please use the appropriate iTextSharp image classes.

Comment: Yes they can. If I use a new document and the mentioned image classes they work fine. I just want to insert into an existing one

Comment: Hostile, obnoxious responses are not appreciated.

Comment: It's fine. No one appreciates being condescended though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Question:**

You have a PDF with a colored JPG. For instance: [image.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/image.pdf)

If you look inside this PDF, you'll see that the filter of the image stream is `/DCTDecode` and the color space is `/DeviceRGB`.

Now you want to replace the image in the PDF, so that the result looks like this: [image_replaced.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/image_replaced.pdf)

In this PDF, the filter is `/FlateDecode` and the color space is change to `/DeviceGray`.

In the conversion process, you want to user a PNG format.

**The Example:**

I have made you an example that makes this conversion: [ReplaceImage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/ReplaceImage)

I will explain this example step by step:

**Step 1: finding the image**

In my example, I know that there's only one image, so I'm retrieving the `PRStream` with the image dictionary and the image bytes in a quick and dirty way.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
PdfDictionary resources = page.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
PdfDictionary xobjects = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
PdfName imgRef = xobjects.getKeys().iterator().next();
PRStream stream = (PRStream) xobjects.getAsStream(imgRef);
```

I go to the `/XObject` dictionary with the `/Resources` listed in the page dictionary of page 1.
I take the first XObject I encounter, assuming that it is an imagem and I get that image as a `PRStream` object.

Your code is better than mine, but this part of the code isn't relevant to your question and it works in the context of my example, so let's ignore the fact that this won't work for other PDFs. What you really care about are steps 2 and 3.

**Step 2: converting the colored JPG into a black and white PNG**

Let's write a method that takes a `PdfImageObject` and that converts it into an `Image` object that is changed into gray colors and stored as a PNG:

```
public static Image makeBlackAndWhitePng(PdfImageObject image) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
    BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
    newBi.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(newBi, "png", baos);
    return Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

We convert the original image into a black and white image using standard `BufferedImage` manipulations: we draw the original image `bi` to a new image `newBi` of type `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`.

Once this is done, you want the image bytes in the PNG format. This is also done using standard `ImageIO` functionaltiy: we just write the `BufferedImage` to a byte array telling `ImageIO` that we want `"png"`.

We can use the resulting bytes to create an `Image` object.

```
Image img = makeBlackAndWhitePng(new PdfImageObject(stream));
```

Now we have an iText `Image` object, but please note that the image bytes as stored in this `Image` object are no longer in the PNG format. As already mentioned in the comments, PNG is not supported in PDF. iText will change the image bytes into a format that is supported in PDF (for more details see section 4.2.6.2 of [The ABC of PDF](http://itextpdf.com/learn)).

**Step 3: replacing the original image stream with the new image stream**

We now have an `Image` object, but what we really need is to replace the original image stream with a new one and we also need to adapt the image dictionary as `/DCTDecode` will change into `/FlateDecode`, `/DeviceRGB` will change into `/DeviceGray`, and the value of the `/Length` will also be different.

You are creating the image stream and its dictionary manually. That's brave. I leave this job to iText's `PdfImage` object:

```
PdfImage image = new PdfImage(makeBlackAndWhitePng(new PdfImageObject(stream)), "", null);
```

`PdfImage` extends `PdfStream`, and I can now replace the original stream with this new stream:

```
public static void replaceStream(PRStream orig, PdfStream stream) throws IOException {
    orig.clear();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    stream.writeContent(baos);
    orig.setData(baos.toByteArray(), false);
    for (PdfName name : stream.getKeys()) {
        orig.put(name, stream.get(name));
    }
}
```

The order in which you do things here is important. You don't want the `setData()` method to tamper with the length and the filter.

**Step 4: persisting the document after replacing the stream**

I guess it's not hard to figure this part out:

```
replaceStream(stream, image);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

**Problem:**

I am not a C# developer. I know PDF inside-out and I know Java.

- If your problem is caused in step 2, then you'll have to post another question asking how to convert a colored JPEG image into a black and white PNG image.
- If your problem is caused in step 3 (for instance because you are using `/DeviceRGB` instead of `/DeviceGray`), then this answer will solve your problem.